# How to declare 2D vector of strings in c++ with size

Tags: string, vector

vector board(n, string(n, '.'));    Is this is the way to declare 2d vector of strings ??

Comment: You can have a vector of vectors, but std::vector itself is always 1 dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

It's a 1d vector of strings, which in a sense can be considered as a 2d data structure of chars (containing n * n dots). By the way, you probably should write `vector<string>`, not just `vector`, to get your definition compiled.

If you really want a **2d data structure of strings**, you need to write

```
vector<vector<string>> board(n, vector<string>(n, string(n, '.')));
```

This code actually creates a 3d data structure containing n * n * n dots.

Comment: Thank you!! That mistake was due to copy-pasting 

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 vector<string> board(4, string(4, '.'));
 
 for(int i=0; i<board.size(); i++){
     cout<<board[i]<<endl;
 }
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

....

....

....

....

so this is like - `['....', '....','....','....']`
since it's a string, it feels like a 2D vector, but it isnt. Here `board[0]= '....'` and since its a string so `board[0][0] = '.'`

but if u define like this :

```
vector<vector<string>> board(4, vector<string>(4, "."));
```

board will be equal to : `[['.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.'],['.', '.', '.', '.'],['.', '.', '.', '.'],['.', '.', '.', '.']]`
surely a 2D vector.

Here `board[0]` `=` `['.', '.', '.', '.']` and `board[0][0] = '.'`

Also Good Luck With N-Queen Problem in Leetcode!